# go programming language: json marshalling

Tags: go

I'm expecting {"a":"42","b":"78"} from the following code, but it doesn't do it.

```
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
)

type S struct {
 A int  `json:"a,string"`
 B *int `json:"b,string"`
}

func main() {
 var s S
 json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"a":"42","b":"78"}`), &s)
 m, _ := json.Marshal(s)
 fmt.Println(string(m))
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it is inten ded or not, but for B you give a pointer type. `B *int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with 1.3 of the go language.

see https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8587